# Using Conditional Statement in ArcGIS Deasktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-9.3

I'm having trouble performing calculations with single output map algebra ArcgIS 9.3 using conditional statements and applying it to several model outputs as they are generated: The statement is:

```
Con(dem%n%<= -0.02,1)
```

I have tried these:

```
Con('dem%n%' <= -0.02,1)
```

and

```
Con("dem%n%" <= -0.02,1)
```

but they seems unstable. What would be a better solution?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? We cannot tell from the question because your use of `Con` does not conform to its syntax, making it unintelligible.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you are using the format: `Con(<condition>, <true_expression>, <false_expression>)`

Based on your question are you using %n% as a form of wildcard for your 'several model outputs'?

There is a [Con (Spatial Analyst)](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?topicname=con_) tool which may help you format your expression and use it in a model.